# How to retrieve the data on a single row?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with some data, something like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |   Column5   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
| 38073   |      16 | abc     |     444 | 4/28/2015   |
| 38076   |      70 | gug     |     555 | 4/30/2015   |
| 38098   |      13 | yyy     |     111 | 5/12/2015   |
| 38098   |      13 | yyy     |     112 | 5/13/2015   |
| 38098   |      13 | yyy     |     113 | 5/14/2015   |
| 38098   |      13 | yyy     |     114 | 5/15/2015   |
| 38100   |      17 | abc     |     115 | 5/13/2015   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is to have the values from Columns 4 and 5 on a single row, something like this :

```
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  Col1   | Col4Val1 | Col5Val1  | Col4Val2 | Col5Val2  | Col4Val3 | Col5Val3  | Col4Val4 |  Col5Val4   |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 38073   |      444 | 4/28/2015 | null     | null      | null     | null      | null     | null        |
| 38076   |      555 | 4/30/2015 | null     | null      | null     | null      | null     | null        |
| 38098   |      111 | 5/12/2015 | 112      | 5/13/2015 | 113      | 5/14/2015 | 114      | 5/15/2015   |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

Appreciate the help if possible.

Thank you.

Bogdan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` to unpivot the data with a `CTE`, then `PIVOT` the columns. You can achieve this dynamically too, there are hundreds of articles that will show you how to do that:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [Column1], CAST([Column4] AS VARCHAR) AS [ColumnVals], 'Col4Val'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Column1] ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR) AS [Pivot]
FROM  Table1
UNION
SELECT [Column1], [Column5], 'Col5Val'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Column1] ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR) AS [Pivot]
FROM  Table1)
SELECT [Column1], [Col4Val1], [Col5Val1], [Col4Val2], [Col5Val2], [Col4Val3], [Col5Val3], [Col4Val4], [Col5Val4]
FROM CTE
PIVOT (MAX([ColumnVals]) FOR [Pivot] IN ([Col4Val1], [Col5Val1], [Col4Val2], [Col5Val2], [Col4Val3], [Col5Val3], [Col4Val4], [Col5Val4])) PIV
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e992f/1